How to find index of value in JSON with powershell
I have a follow json and I need to find an index of value
{
  "backendAddresses": [
    {
      "ipAddress": "1.2.1.10"
    },
    {
      "ipAddress": "1.2.1.9"
    }
  ]
}

With bash and jq it's simple, let's say json is a variable $ip so
echo $ip | jq '[.backendAddresses[].ipAddress] |index ("1.2.1.10")'
0
echo $ip | jq '[.backendAddresses[].ipAddress] |index ("1.2.1.9")'
1

returns you index, 1, 0, etc.
What would be the easiest way to do the same with only pwsh on windows ?
I've tried something like this but it returns nothing :(
echo ($ip.backendAddresses |? {$_.ipAddress -eq "1.2.1.10"}).id

Thanks everyone ! This one worked just fine for me
$obj = $ip | ConvertFrom-Json

0..($ip.backendAddresses.ipAddress.Count-1)|?{$ip.backendAddresses.ipAddress[$_] -eq '1.2.1.9'}


https://ncox.dev/blog/jq-powershell/

PowerShell automatically flattens nested array access operations, so you can do 0..($ip.backendAddresses.ipAddress.Count-1)|?{$ip.backendAddresses.ipAddress[$_] -eq '1.2.1.9'} in PowerShell

As your $ip object hasn't any connection with Json anymore, you could consider using the Get-Node of this ObjectraphTools module: $Ip | Get-Node "backendAddresses.ipAddress='1.2.1.9'.." which returns a PSNode along with the Name property which contains your index and also lets you directly access and change its value, e.g.: ($Ip | Get-Node "backendAddresses.ipAddress='1.2.1.9'").Value = '1.2.3.4'

Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen !
At the beginning it didn't work, saying
InvalidOperation: Cannot index into a null array.

But after I converted it to PS object like
$obj = $ip | ConvertFrom-Json

It worked ! Thanks !
@iRon
Not sure why but it just returns
Get-Node: The term 'Get-Node' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

I assume it can be added but example from Mathias works as it is :)
Thanks everyone !
